# Why does rendering the camera view with react-webcam work on phone browser, but not after downloading as pwa?

Tags: reactjs, camera

To clarify, the example above runs on a deplyoed react frontend. And works fine on iOS Safari. It renders the camera view. But after downloading the app as a PWA it doesn't render the camera view anymoe.

Is there some limitation on pwa's on using the camera that is not present in the browser? Running on iOS.

Can be replicated by just running the example code below from the react-webcam readme.

https://github.com/mozmorris/react-webcam

````
const videoConstraints = {
  width: 1280,
  height: 720,
  facingMode: "user"
};

const WebcamCapture = () => {
  const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
  const capture = React.useCallback(
    () => {
      const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
    },
    [webcamRef]
  );
  return (
    <>
      <Webcam
        audio={false}
        height={720}
        ref={webcamRef}
        screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
        width={1280}
        videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
      />
      <button onClick={capture}>Capture photo</button>
    </>
  );
};```
````